# git Blame -L '/^<<<</,/^>>>>/' -- {filename}

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to find the author of the conflicted lines. I try this command:

```
git blame -L '/^<<<</,/^>>>>/' -- {filename}
```

But I'm getting error:

> usage: git blame [options] [rev-opts] [rev] [--] file

Comment: Seems like it should work. What shell are you using and/or are you on Windows? (I think some Windows shells are fussy about quote characters, not that I know for sure since I don't use Windows...)

Comment: Yes I'm using Windows only. I tried the same thing in got bash command prompt also still facing the same issue.